# VIM - Automatically closing jinja statements

Tags: vim, jinja2

I wonder how to automatically close jinja statements, like html tags.

 For example when I type `{% for foo in bar %}`, `{% endfor %}` is automatically added two lines below and the cursor in the middle.

 I checked how it's done with [HTML tags](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9672/how-to-generate-closing-tags-for-html), but I'm not good enough at vim script to adapt this to my problem.

Answer (score -2):

[vim endwise](https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise) can help here, though you may need to do some work to set it up for jinja.

**EDIT** from reading the plugin code it should work automatically if the filetype is `htmljinja` or `jinja.html`